# Contour Integral representation Hurwitz Zeta Function over Hankel Contour

Tags: integration, contour-integration, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am trying to prove the following contour integral representation of the Hurwitz zeta Function that appears [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#E30).

$$\zeta(s,a)=\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2 \pi i}\int_{H}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz \tag{1}$$

With $s \neq 1$ and $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$.

It´s taken over a Hankel contour which is a loop around the negative real axis. It starts at $-\infty$, encircles the origin once in the positive direction without enclosing any of the points $\pm 2 \pi i,\pm 4 \pi i, \cdots$ and returns to $-\infty$ acording to the picture below

[image]

So we have the following

$$\int_{H}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz=\int_{C_L}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz+\int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz+\int_{C_U}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz \tag{2}$$

**My question is around the procedure I took to prove that the integral $\int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz $ around the circle vanishes in the limit $ \epsilon \to 0$**

We start by calculating the two integrals over the straight lines:

Over the bottom edge of the contour we let $z=xe^{-i \pi}$

$$
\begin{align} 
I_{C_L}&=\int_{C_L}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz\\
&=\int_R^\epsilon \frac{(xe^{-i \pi})^{s-1}e^{axe^{-i \pi}}}{1-e^{xe^{-i \pi}}}\,e^{-i \pi}dx\\
&=-e^{-i \pi s}\int_\epsilon^R \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx \tag{3}
 \end{align}
$$

On the upper edge we let $z=xe^{i \pi}$

$$
\begin{align} 
I_{C_U}&=\int_{C_U}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz\\
&=\int_\epsilon^R \frac{(xe^{i \pi})^{s-1}e^{axe^{i \pi}}}{1-e^{xe^{i \pi}}}\,e^{i \pi}dx\\
&=e^{i \pi s}\int_\epsilon^R \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx \tag{4}
 \end{align}
$$

For the integral over the circle we should consider $z =\epsilon e^{i \theta}$. We want to show that this integral vanishes in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.  then:

$$
\begin{aligned} 
I_{C_\epsilon}&=\int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\left( \epsilon e^{i \theta}\right)^{s-1}e^{a\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\,i \epsilon e^{i \theta}d \theta\\
&=i \epsilon^s  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{is \theta}e^{a\epsilon\left(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta) \right) }}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\,d \theta\\
&=i \epsilon^s  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{is \theta}e^{a\epsilon\left(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta) \right) }}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}d \theta\\
&=i \epsilon^s  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\frac{e^{is \theta}e^{a\epsilon\left(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta) \right) }}{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}d \theta\\
& \leq \Bigg|i \epsilon^s  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\frac{e^{is \theta}e^{a\epsilon\left(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta) \right) }}{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}d \theta  \Bigg|\\
& \leq \epsilon^s \int_{-\pi}^\pi \Bigg|\frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\Bigg| \, \Bigg|\frac{e^{is \theta}e^{a\epsilon\left(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta) \right) }}{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}\Bigg|\,d \theta\\
& \leq \epsilon^{s-1} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \Bigg|\frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\Bigg| \, e^{a\epsilon \cos(\theta)}\,d \theta\\
& \leq \epsilon^{s-1} C \int_{-\pi}^\pi  e^{a\epsilon \cos(\theta)}\,d \theta\\
&\\
 \text{taking the limit as} \,\,\epsilon \to 0 \\
& \\
I_{C_\epsilon} &\leq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon^{s-1} C \int_{-\pi}^\pi  e^{a\epsilon \cos(\theta)}\,d \theta\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon^{s-1} C \int_{-\pi}^\pi  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  e^{a\epsilon \cos(\theta)}\,d \theta\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon^{s-1}  2 \pi C \to 0 \qquad \text{for s}>1
 \end{aligned}
$$

To prove the boundedness of $\Bigg|\frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}\Bigg|$ I procedured as following:

$$
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{1-e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}}&=\frac{z}{1-e^{z}}\\
&=\frac{z}{1-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \right)}\\
&=\frac{z}{1-\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots \right)}\\
&=-\frac{z}{z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots }\\
&=-\frac{z}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2!}+\cdots }\\
&=-\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2!}+\cdots }\\
&=-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}{2!}+\cdots }\\
& \text{as} \,\,\epsilon \to 0 \,\,\text{the limit tends to}\,\,-1
 \end{aligned}
$$

Taking limit of $R \to \infty $ and $\epsilon \to 0$ we obtain

$$
\begin{aligned} 
\int_{H}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz&=e^{i \pi s}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx-e^{-i \pi s}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx\\
&=2i \sin(\pi s)\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx\\
&=2i \sin(\pi s)\Gamma(s)\zeta(s,a)\\
&=\frac{2 \pi i}{\Gamma(1-s)}\zeta(s,a)\\
 \end{aligned}
$$

Or

$$\zeta(s,a)=\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2 \pi i}\int_{H}\frac{ z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1-e^z}\,dz$$

**So summing up, my questions are: (i) whether the procedure to show that the integral around the circle vanishes is correct. (ii) I assumed $s>1$ , but in the [link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#E30) it says that $s \neq 1$, how can I reconcile this apparently divergent assumptions?**

Comment: It provides the analytic continuation to $\Bbb{C}-\Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$. As you saw the connexion to the usual series definition of $\zeta(s,a)$ is obvious only for $\Re(s) > 1$ (anyway the series diverges elsewhere). This is standard in analytic continuation procedures.

Comment: @reuns Thank you! Actually my ultimate goal is to close this contour, calculate the residues @ $\pm 2 \pi i n$, show that the integral along the big arc vanishes as well. The result should give the fourier expansion of the Hurwitz Zeta function.

Comment: @Gary great answer, thank you! I ´ll fix it there.

Comment: @Gary fixed, thank you for the comment!